# Inserting the character "©" into any of the attributes of my json object breaks my php code

Tags: android, mysql, json

I am making an Android application that inserts data into a remote MySQL database.  I am sending a json representation of an arrayList of custom objects to the server which will grab the json object, decode it into an array from which I can get the attributes to insert into my MySQL database.  This process works until a character like "©" is present in json attribute. When this happens, the json_decode(someJsonObject) nolonger recognises the "someJsonObject" even though I have validated it (via http://jsonlint.com). please can someone help?

I have checked my php.ini file and the default_charset  is set to "UTF-8".  I believe Android SQlite is utf-8 encoded (but I'm not really sure how to check this as there seems to be nothing on the Android developers site about this). The Android manifest file however, does indicate at the top that "encoding = utf=8".

json object that fails to be decoded:

> ```
>    [{"abstractText":"Ebola viruses and Marburg viruses include some of the most virulent     and fatal   pathogens known to humans. These viruses cause severe haemorrhagic fevers, with case fatality rates in the range 25-90%. The diagnosis of filovirus using formalin-fixed tissues from fatal cases poses a significant challenge. The most characteristic histopathological findings are seen in the liver; however, the findings overlap with many other viral and non-viral haemorrhagic diseases. The need to distinguish filovirus infections from other haemorrhagic fevers, particularly in areas with multiple endemic viral haemorrhagic agents, is of paramount importance. In this review we discuss the current state of knowledge of filovirus infections and their pathogenesis, including histopathological findings, epidemiology, modes of transmission and filovirus entry and spread within host organisms. The pathogenesis of filovirus infections is complex and involves activation of the mononuclear phagocytic system, with release of pro-inflammatory cytokines, chemokines and growth factors, endothelial dysfunction, alterations of the innate and adaptive immune systems, direct organ and endothelial damage from unrestricted viral replication late in infection, and coagulopathy. Although our understanding of the pathogenesis of filovirus infections has rapidly increased in the past few years, many questions remain unanswered. Copyright © 2014 Pathological Society of Great Britain and Ireland. Published by John Wiley \u0026 Sons, Ltd.","authorString":"Martines RB, Ng DL, Greer PW, Rollin PE, Zaki SR.","issue":"2","journalTitle":"J. Pathol.","pageInfo":"153-174","pmid":"25297522","pubYear":"2015","title":"Tissue and cellular tropism, pathology and pathogenesis of Ebola and Marburg viruses.","volume":"235"}]
> ```

Converting my arrayList of custom objects to json representation:

```
    ArrayList<Article> list;
    list = recallSharedListFromDb();


    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    String json_arrayList = gson.toJson(list);


   // Build parameters. 
    List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonObj", json_object));


     * submitting data to server. check logcat for json response.
     */
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_register_code, "POST", param);

    // Read json response coming from server.
    Log.d("SyncToMySQL", "json string: "+ json.toString());
```

Comment: Can you post your full JSON object?

Comment: i've updated.please see above.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change your JSON Format UTF to ISO. Hope this Helps

Comment: please could you tell me how to do that? I'm new to all this.

Comment: please post some code, so that i can check how you are converting web service data into string.